# Java is saving input integers as ASCII

Tags: java

Basically, I'm testing saving/reading from files and made a DetailsManager class to communicate with "Details.txt".

The `save();` method is supposed to take the inputs, write them to the file, and update the attributes. When given "0" as an age input, it is correctly placed into the text file and printing out this.age from inside `save();` will give out "0".

Then when I try to get the value, either by `getAge();` or when I directly call `Dets.Age;` from another class, it sends out "48", the ASCII of "0", instead of "0".

Even printing out from `getAge();` also returns "48". Why does it do that and how can I fix it?

The code:

```
package mainpack;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class DetailsManager {

    private String fileName = "Details.txt";

    String usrname = "Guest";
    private int age = 0;
    private char ds ='f';
    Boolean dontshow = false;

    public int getAge() {
        System.out.println("THE AGE IS:"+this.age);// THIS ONE PRINTS 48
        return age;
    }

    public void refresh() {
        try {
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
            usrname = bufferedReader.readLine();
            age = bufferedReader.read();
            ds = (char) bufferedReader.read();

            if(ds == 't')dontshow = true;
            else dontshow = false;

            bufferedReader.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex1) {
            System.out.println("Unable to open file '" + fileName + "'");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error reading file '" + fileName + "'");
        }
    }

    public void save(String usrname, Integer age, boolean dontshow) {
        this.usrname = usrname;
        this.age = age;

        this.dontshow = dontshow;
        if(dontshow == true) this.ds = 't';
        else this.ds = 'f';

        System.out.println("THE AGE2 IS:"+this.age);// THIS ONE PRINTS 0

        PrintWriter printWriter;
        try {
            printWriter = new PrintWriter("./Details.txt");
            printWriter.println(this.usrname);
            printWriter.println(this.age);
            printWriter.println(this.ds);
            printWriter.close();


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found. Someone was messing with my files again..");
        }
    }

}
```

This is what "Details.txt" looks like:

```
Guest
0
f
```

Comment: Show us the example content of Details.txt file

Comment: [`BufferedReader.read()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#read()) reads *a single character*. It returns an `int` representing that character and that's what you are getting. You print out individual, formatted, lines, formatted, but read back single, raw characters.

Comment: As a side note, if(ds == 't')dontshow = true; else dontshow = false; is equivalent to dontshow = (ds == 't'); A little bit easier to read IMO

Comment: Added. Thanks ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is not in the getAge method. If you try by yourself and create a new instance of your class, and call getAge() right after, you will see return the right value.

If after tinkering with it with your refresh() or save() method it returns 42, that means that's the ASCII value of a *. Do you have any * in your file Details.txt? If this doesn't help you, can we see your main method?

Comment: You're right the problem was inside the refresh(); method. bufferedReader.read(); was reading 0 as an ASCII instead of an integer ^^ Thanks for the help.

Comment: 0 as an ASCII should have return 48, not 42. However, in java you can cast any int into char and any char into int without any problem. Happy I helped! EDIT: I just saw that you changed 42 to 48 in your post :)